# Assign Azure Blueprints on a Subscription Level using REST APIs

Tags: azure, rest, azure-rest-api, azure-blueprints

I need to use REST APIs to create, publish and assign Azure Blueprints on a **Subscription** level. I went through the documentation 
[https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/governance/blueprints/create-blueprint-rest-api#:~:text=as%20v20180622%2D135541.-,Assign%20a%20blueprint,be%20assigned%20to%20that%20subscription](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/governance/blueprints/create-blueprint-rest-api#:%7E:text=as%20v20180622%2D135541.-,Assign%20a%20blueprint,be%20assigned%20to%20that%20subscription).
This documentation only has APIs to create, publish and assign from **Management Group** level. I however changed the API calls from

```
PUT https://management.azure.com/providers/Microsoft.Management/managementGroups/{YourMG}/providers/Microsoft.Blueprint/blueprints/MyBlueprint?api-version=2018-11-01-preview
```

to

```
PUT https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{{subscriptionId}}/providers/Microsoft.Blueprint/blueprints/MyBlueprint?api-version=2018-11-01-preview
```

and it worked fine. I could even create artifacts using a similar way, but I'm not able to run assign command. I get **403 Forbidden** The problem is, since blueprint is already defined at Subscription level, there is some change in the assign request too. Can anyone please help? Thanks

Comment: Did you change the scope to subscription in the JSON body of the request?

Comment: Yes I have @Ken. The problem is that, we need Owner access to the service principal for assigning the blueprint. Every other operations can be done with default service principal access(contributor). Even deletion of blueprint can be done using contributor access. That is the reason it was difficult to figure out where I was going wrong. Yes, once I changed service principal to the one with owner access, I'm getting proper response to the request. I'm however now facing issue in the Portal. It is not getting assigned. It remains in waiting and I get timeout error after 5 mins.